# How to test trigger that compares Trigger.new with Trigger.old

Tags: trigger, unit-test, update

I have a simple trigger that runs on Account update, and the only logic is a check to whether or now BillingPostalCode changes or not.

This is my code:

```
trigger ZipCodeUpdated on Account (before update) {
    for(Integer i=0; i<Trigger.new.size(); i++){
        if(Trigger.new[i].BillingPostalCode != Trigger.old[i].BillingPostalCode){
            ZipCodeUpdatedHelper.InitialCheck(Trigger.new, Trigger.old);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how the test class should look like, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unit tests in Salesforce will generally look the same no matter what it is you're trying to test. There are a few exceptions, but this trigger isn't one of them. If you haven't already looked through https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244788/how-do-i-write-an-apex-unit-test, you should. It also contains a link to the [Apex Testing module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_testing) on trailhead (which will help you with the general structure of tests).

Comment: Also, you should consider using the `Trigger.oldMap` context variable to access the old record (allowing you to use `for(Account acct :trigger.new)` instead of `for(Integer i=0; i<Trigger.new.size(); i++)`). You also probably don't want to be calling your `ZipCodeUpdatedHelper.InitialCheck()` method on _every_ iteration (and not passing all trigger records to it when you do). Having your loop create Lists of records to process, and then calling your method _outside of the loops_ (passing the Lists your loop populated) is a better approach.

Comment: @DerekF thanks, that's valuable knowledge, I'll take that into consideration!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a basic level, you simply create a record, then change the value in memory, and update:

```
Account record = new Account(BillingPostalCode='12345',...);
insert record;
record.BillingPostalCode = '54321';
Test.startTest();
update record;
Test.stopTest();
// remember to check to make sure your logic ran.
```