# Apex Test Class Fetching Article Details

Tags: apex, unit-test, controller, class, knowledge

I need help with writing an apex test class for a class that fetches article titles and article descriptions. Class for example:

```java
global class FetchingArticleDetails{

    global List<(API name of the knowledge object)> Records {get; set;}

    global FetchingArticleDetails (){
        Records = [select Article_Description__c, Title from (API name of the knowledge object) where UrlName='Something-FAQ'];
    }
}
```

Class is working as a controller on visualforce page very well I just need to write the test so I can deploy it into production

```java
@isTest
public with sharing class FetchingArticleDetailsTest {
    @isTest
    static void methodCheckArticleDetails(){
        Knowledge__kav knObj = new Knowledge__kav(
            UrlName='Something-something'
        );
        insert knObj;
        
        Exception failureDuringExecution = null;
        Test.StartTest();
        FetchingArticleDetails ad = new FetchingArticleDetails();
        try{
            ad.FetchingArticleDetails();
        }
        catch(Exception failure){
            failureDuringExecution=failure;
        }
        Test.StopTest();
    }
}
```

Did this but getting Method does not exist or incorrect signature error

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: There is usually not much difference in writing tests for Feature X (e.g. Knowledge articles) compared to writing tests for anything else. You should start by reading [How do I write an Apex unit test?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244788/how-do-i-write-an-apex-unit-test) from our [tag:canonical-qa] tagged questions, give writing a test on your own a shot, and then come back here if you run into a specific issue (like inserting a knowledge article for a test).

Comment: Agree with Derek, but Knowledge does have some exceptions. E.g. if you are dependent on the Article being published: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.knowledge_dev.meta/knowledge_dev/apex_KbManagement_PublishingService_publishArticle.htm

Comment: Thank you guys for answering, I read everything about the apex unit test, also did the trails , just couldn't find anywhere online that someone did a test for a class that does a similar thing in a similar way as my class is doing. This is my first apex project so I am quite confused. I understand that I need to use System.assertEquals and check if the title from class is the same as the title I wanted but just don't know how to call it string articleTitle= ??
            System.assertEquals('the title of article',articleTitle);

Comment: @DerekF @ isTest

public with sharing class FetchingArticleDetailsTest {
@ isTest
    static void methodCheckArticleDetails(){
        Knowledge__kav knObj= new Knowledge__kav(
        UrlName='Something-something'
        );
        insert knObj;
   
        Exception failureDuringExecution=null;
        Test.StartTest();
         FetchingArticleDetails ad = new FetchingArticleDetails();
        try{
            ad.FetchingArticleDetails();
        }
        catch(Exception failure){
            failureDuringExecution=failure;
        }
        Test.StopTest();
    }
}

Comment: @DerekF Tried this but getting method doesn't exist error

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include that (code is really hard to read in comments if it's more than one line long).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, tests follow the "AAA"  pattern

- Arrange, by creating/inserting your test data
- Act, by calling the one method you want to test
- Assert, by gathering the results of running the test and comparing them to what you expect

The results you care about are mostly things that you have direct control over. That covers things like the return value you get from a method, changes to publically visible class variables (public class state), how many callouts you made (before running the test vs after), SObject records that you create/update/delete, etc...

How you gather results depends on what the result is. If you created an SObject record and inserted it, you'll probably need to query for it. If you are making callouts, you can have a simple integer in your HttpCalloutMock class to verify that you actually made the callout. Things like that.

Given what you have so far, the result that you have control over is *what data ends up in your `records` member variable for your `FetchingArticleDetails` class*. Your class doesn't have any methods, only a constructor. So to test that, you need to execute something like `FetchingArticleDetails testInstance = new FetchingArticleDetails();`

`testInstance.fetchingArticleDetails();` is incorrect. We use dot notation to call methods, and the `new` keyword to call constructors.

Since you have an instance of your class, you can access its member variables using dot-notation (`testInstance.records`).

When you have a List to assert against, you'll usually end up writing a loop. Checking to make sure that you have the right number (or not an obviously wrong number) of items in your list is also a good idea.

Some example assertions might be

```
// assertEquals() and assertNotEquals() only need 2 arguments, but it's good practice
//   to specify a third argument.
// That controls the message that you'll see if the assertion fails, and can be
//   really helpful in narrowing down the problem (if your message is good enough)
System.assertEquals(false, testInstance.records.isEmpty(), 'Should have gotten at least one KAV from the query in the constructor');

// The reason why you want to have an assertion on if the list is empty or not is because
//   if your list _is_ empty, this loop would not execute.
// That would mean your test passes when it really should be failing
for(MyKnowledge__kav article :testInstance.records){
    System.assertEquals('My test article name', article.name, 'Article name is wrong');
}
```

#### One final comment

Try/catch blocks in normal code where you do nothing inside of the `catch` block (or only something like writing to the debug log) are bad. That causes the exceptions to be swallowed, making it appear that things are fine when there really is a problem. It also makes it harder to figure out the issue that's causing the exception.

Try/catch inside of tests is worse (unless you're writing a test where you expect a specific exception to be thrown, where throwing an exception is expected behavior).

The purpose of tests (aside from letting you deploy code) is to catch issues early. If there is a problem somewhere, you *want* tests to fail so that you can be alerted to the issue and fix it.