# Can we use DML statements between test.startTest and test.stopTest apex test classes?

Tags: apex, unit-test

I am writing unit test classes for trigger. Can we use dml statements within Test.Starttest and test.stopTest? What is the best practise?

```
Test.StartTest();
insert exList;
Test.StopTest();
```

Can I use Delete dml statement within try..catch?

```
Test.StartTest();
try{
    Delete exList;
}
catch(Exception e){
    System.debug(e.getMessage());
}
Test.StopTest();
```

Comment: See https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/244788/81648 and visit its links.

Answer (score 2):

See this [Using Limits, startTest, and stopTest](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_tools_start_stop_test.htm).

A short version of this is that `Test.startTest()` gives you a new set of governor limits and `Test.stopTest()` runs any outstanding asynchronous work. So if necessary code a unit test like this:

```
@IsTest
static void myTestMethod() {

    // Initialise data

    Test.startTest();

    // Invoke the code you are testing

    Test.stopTest();

    // Assert the results
}
```

But for many tests the features of `Test.startTest()` and `Test.stopTest()` are not needed so they can and should be left out.

On your specific questions:

- Yes you can do a DML insert as you illustrate (to e.g. make a trigger run)
- Yes you can do a DML delete as you illustrate, but unless you are trying to invoke an error condition, best to not include `try/catch` in your test and instead just let the test fail and the test runner will report the exception if an exception is thrown.

On a broader point about testing triggers, some people may argue that extracting the trigger logic out into separate Apex classes and  calling those classes directly is a good way to go. Personally, I always test triggers - whether they have inline code or code extracted out into classes - by performing DML in the unit tests as there are fine-grained details related to e.g. whether the trigger is `before` or `after` that need to be covered by the tests to assert a trigger's actual behaviour in the running software.