# Creating an Apex Test Class for Apex class that handles a webhook integration when an opportunity in Salesforce moves to the 'Closed Won' stage

Tags: apex, unit-test

How can I create a test class on the below trigger?

```
public class webhookOpportunityStageNameClosedWon {
    
    // call method 'handleOpportunityStageNameClosedWon' in the 'webhookOpportunityStageNameClosedWon' class when Opportunity.StageName is updated to 'Closed Won'
     public static void handleOpportunityStageNameClosedWon(List<Opportunity> opportunities) {
        for (Opportunity opp : opportunities) {
            if(opp.StageName == 'Closed Won') {
                
                // call webhook and pass Salesforce data in JSON format
                HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
                req.setEndpoint('https://endpoint.com/example');
                req.setMethod('POST');
                req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                req.setHeader('x-api-key', 'endpointexample');
                
                // build the JSON payload
                Map<String, Object> payload = new Map<String, Object>();
                List<Map<String, Object>> teams = new List<Map<String, Object>>();
                teams.add(new Map<String, Object>{
                                                  'team_name' => opp.Account.Name,
                                                  'player_gender' => opp.Team_Gender__c,
                                                  'player_birth_year' => opp.Team_Birth_Year__c,
                                                  'sport_type' => opp.Sport__c
                                                  });
                payload.put('teams', teams);
                List<Map<String, Object>> contacts = new List<Map<String, Object>>();
                for (Contact contact : opp.Account.Contacts) {
                    contacts.add(new Map<String, Object>{
                            'first_name' => contact.FirstName,
                            'last_name' => contact.LastName,
                            'email' => contact.Email,
                            'phone' => contact.Phone,
                            'role' => contact.User_Type__c
                            });
                    }
                payload.put('contacts', contacts);
                payload.put('deal_id', opp.Id);
                payload.put('deal_type', opp.Opportunity_Type__c);
                payload.put('deal_name', opp.Name);
                
                // convert payload to JSON string and set as request body
                String body = JSON.serialize(payload);
                req.setBody(body);
                
                // send request
                Http http = new Http();
                HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
                
                // verify response and update division_id in salesforce on success; log on error
                if (res.getStatusCode() >= 200 && res.getStatusCode() < 300) {
                    String responseBody = res.getBody();
                    Map<String, Object> responseMap = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
                    Map<String, Object> dataMap = (Map<String, Object>) responseMap.get('data');
                    Decimal division_id = Decimal.valueOf((String) dataMap.get('division_id'));
                    
                    Account account = [SELECT Id, Division_Id__c FROM Account WHERE Id = :opp.AccountId];
                    account.Division_ID__c = division_id;
                    update account;
                    
                } else if (res.getStatusCode() >= 400 && res.getStatusCode() < 500) {
                    String errorMsg = 'client error resp: ' + res.getStatus();
                    System.debug(errorMsg);
                    
                } else { 
                    String errorMsg = 'error resp: ' + res.getStatus();
                    System.debug(errormsg);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this discussion answer your question [Wrting unit test](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244788/how-do-i-write-an-apex-unit-test)

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Including what you've tried so far and being _very detailed_ is important here. Questions on testing are very common, so the community has put together some catch-all "canonical-qa" questions. The first one I've marked this as a duplicate of goes over tests in general, and the second one goes into more specifics about what to do when you're making a callout.